# JMS producer/consumer for queue in JBOSS 7.1 Final

Tags: jboss, jms

I am unable to create Producer/consumer for JMS queue. I tried using port 1099 as well as 4447.

```
private static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Properties p = new Properties( );
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES," org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");

        return new javax.naming.InitialContext();

}
```

Getting error : unable to connect to port 1099.

Can anyone suggest how to provide property for InitialContext.

Comment: p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are using a startup config which does not depend on the messaging module - the default `standalone.xml` is such a case. You could try starting the server with the `standalone-full.xml` to get the messaging running in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Kostja. As you suggest, I start server by CMD *standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml* but still showing error **javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]**

Answer (score 0):

Port 1099 is no longer used in JBoss 7 for JNDI lookups.  It was used by the JNP project in previous JBoss version.  The JNP project has been replaced by the jboss-remoting-naming project which uses 4447 and may require additional properties when configuring your IntialContext.

For more information on how to use the new libraries please refer to [Remote EJB invocations via JNDI - EJB client API or remote-naming project](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project).